# Ubuntu 18.04 taking atleast 4 min to boot up and show blank screen while boot up

Tags: boot, 18.04, services, systemd-networkd, systemd-journald

I tried to look at critical chain and I managed to fix some but couldn't find more on this. I also tried to remove snap packages and their dependencies. Earlier systemd-journal-flush was also making problem but I cleared that out. I'm not a expert on kernel codes and dependencies.

`$ systemd-analyze critical-chain`

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4min 11.302s
└─multi-user.target @4min 11.302s
  └─systemd-user-sessions.service @4min 1.267s +4ms
    └─network.target @1min 336ms
      └─NetworkManager.service @42.894s +17.440s
        └─dbus.service @39.872s
          └─basic.target @39.871s
            └─sockets.target @39.871s
              └─docker.socket @39.466s +404ms
                └─sysinit.target @39.460s
                  └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @36.636s +358ms
                    └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @36.636s
                      └─system.slice @5.201s
                        └─-.slice @5.142s
```

`$ systemd-analyze blame`

```
         43.632s docker.service
         39.533s dev-sdb5.device
         30.555s snapd.service
         24.986s systemd-journal-flush.service
         23.497s postgresql@10-main.service
         21.591s dev-loop24.device
         21.479s dev-loop26.device
         21.376s dev-loop27.device
         21.346s dev-loop15.device
         21.328s dev-loop25.device
         21.048s dev-loop28.device
         20.838s dev-loop19.device
         20.677s dev-loop23.device
         20.587s dev-loop20.device
         20.122s dev-loop21.device
         20.054s dev-loop22.device
         19.873s networkd-dispatcher.service
         19.675s libvirtd.service
         19.322s dev-loop11.device
         18.486s dev-loop18.device
         18.436s dev-loop14.device
         18.295s dev-loop17.device
         17.937s dev-loop16.device
         17.440s NetworkManager.service
         17.379s uml-utilities.service
         16.427s dev-loop8.device
         16.324s dev-loop10.device
         16.263s dev-loop12.device
         16.105s dev-loop13.device
         15.876s gpu-manager.service
         15.461s dev-loop9.device
         12.203s apport-autoreport.service
         11.914s dev-loop4.device
         11.668s dev-loop6.device
         11.510s dev-loop0.device
         11.453s dev-loop7.device
         11.212s dev-loop2.device
         11.137s dev-loop5.device
         10.889s dev-loop3.device
         10.065s dev-loop1.device
         10.026s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          9.751s upower.service
          9.144s apache2.service
          8.868s udisks2.service
          8.455s systemd-udevd.service
          8.219s ModemManager.service
          6.741s teamviewerd.service
          6.348s vboxdrv.service
          6.007s accounts-daemon.service
          5.996s colord.service
          5.452s systemd-rfkill.service
          5.435s binfmt-support.service
          5.137s dns-clean.service
          5.097s qemu-kvm.service
          4.913s ebtables.service
          4.829s networking.service
          4.777s plymouth-read-write.service
          3.928s systemd-sysctl.service
          3.906s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
          3.479s fwupd.service
          3.366s thermald.service
          3.158s grub-common.service
          2.861s snap-core-9289.mount
          2.859s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
          2.855s console-setup.service
          2.733s wpa_supplicant.service
          2.630s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-145.mount
          2.590s snap-spotify-41.mount
          2.580s lvm2-monitor.service
          2.415s bluetooth.service
          2.363s systemd-modules-load.service
          2.234s apport.service
          2.158s speech-dispatcher.service
          2.076s apparmor.service
          2.005s rsyslog.service
          1.968s snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-748.mount
          1.910s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
          1.909s snap-core18-1754.mount
          1.894s snap-gnome\x2dclocks-257.mount
          1.888s snap-gnome\x2dlogs-93.mount
          1.847s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-100.mount
          1.832s systemd-logind.service
          1.772s avahi-daemon.service
          1.767s alsa-restore.service
          1.762s nvidia-persistenced.service
          1.756s sysstat.service
          1.755s pppd-dns.service
          1.676s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-33.mount
          1.657s snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
          1.657s keyboard-setup.service
          1.585s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
          1.580s snap-postgresql10-47.mount
          1.578s snap-eclipse-40.mount
          1.562s snap-eclipse-48.mount
          1.394s snap-spotify-36.mount
          1.251s snap-core-9066.mount
          1.248s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount
          1.198s snap-sublime\x2dtext-85.mount
          1.188s snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-550.mount
          1.185s systemd-journald.service
          1.079s proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
          1.056s snap-sublime\x2dtext-77.mount
          1.040s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d26\x2d1604-98.mount
          1.028s snap-gnome\x2dclocks-261.mount
          1.005s snap-core18-1705.mount
          1.004s snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-148.mount
           979ms systemd-random-seed.service
           955ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-100.mount
           953ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-539.mount
           953ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-730.mount
           792ms kerneloops.service
           744ms swapfile.swap
           715ms systemd-ask-password-wall.service
           686ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount
           651ms systemd-remount-fs.service
           625ms openvpn.service
           624ms containerd.service
           605ms dev-mqueue.mount
           603ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
           603ms dev-hugepages.mount
           575ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           566ms systemd-resolved.service
           504ms polkit.service
           481ms systemd-update-utmp.service
           468ms plymouth-start.service
           419ms snapd.seeded.service
           409ms snapd.socket
           404ms docker.socket
           358ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
           280ms user@120.service
           211ms libvirt-guests.service
           196ms packagekit.service
           182ms kmod-static-nodes.service
           133ms bolt.service
           120ms user@1000.service
           105ms gdm.service
           104ms blk-availability.service
            90ms ufw.service
            74ms rtkit-daemon.service
            59ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
            37ms setvtrgb.service
            15ms vboxweb-service.service
             9ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             8ms ureadahead-stop.service
             4ms vboxballoonctrl-service.service
             4ms vboxautostart-service.service
             4ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             1ms postgresql.service
             1ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             1ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

Comment: You have too many snap applications, and each one is taking up to 20s to load. Install normal binary .deb files and `snap delete` the similar packages.

Comment: @heynnema, these snaps seem to take less than 20 seconds to load. Where are the remaining 3 minutes ? Pressing ESC on the blank screen may reveal some helpful output. If not, try `journalctl -b`, search for gaps (jumps) in the displayed time and tell us what you did find.